# Where can I find archived ESO/KMOS Science Verification datacubes?

Tags: data-pipeline

Only raw dataframes seem to be in the ESO archive at http://archive.eso.org/wdb/wdb/eso/eso_archive_main/query?prog_id=60.A-9450(A) for the Galactic Centre nuclear cluster programme.

Is there a processed cube elsewhere for SVs as is the case for post-SV programmes?

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example of a processed “post-science-verification” data cube for the Galactic Centre program? (I’m skeptical that they exist.)

Comment: Around the central field on the GC, the archive holds fully processed KMOS cubes from post-SV programmes. The central field taken during SV on the GC was processed ad hoc and results have trickled out, e.g. A&A 584, A2 DOI: 10.1051/0004-6361/201526336 with coverage shown in its Fig. 7. But only the raw frames in the ESO archive. Given the power of KMOS on the GC, I'm perplexed why the SV data were not processed with the final pipeline and the cube put in the archive. Or is it somewhere not obvious that you can't reach through the archive interface?!

Comment: Here's the link to what's in the ESO archive  http://tinyurl.com/2pyebefx   The missing cube is centered on the blue +, same coverage as the post-SV cubes outlined.

Comment: Haven't checked all of the [KMOS SV programs](https://www.eso.org/sci/activities/vltsv/kmossv.html) but all of the ones I have checked don't have processed data available. This is unusual as the SV rules say that the SV proposers "should" (not "must") provide processed versions of SV data. For whatever reason this didn't happen with KMOS; I think you will need to do the processing yourself - [ESO Reflex](https://www.eso.org/sci/software/esoreflex/) and the KMOS pipeline should be able to do it; the archive will be able to give you the needed calibration frames for the marked raw science data.

Comment: OK, thank you for checking. I'll give ESO Reflex a whirl. It's rather sad if KMOS SV frames were indeed never processed through the final pipeline and the cubes archived.

Comment: @geraldcecil I'm pretty sure the only ESO VLT IFU data that is automatically processed into data cubes by the full pipeline is MUSE. Here's an example:
http://archive.eso.org/wdb/wdb/adp/phase3_main/query?collection_name=MUSE&version=&object===NGC4237&order_main=wavelmin%2Cfilter%2Cexp_start%2Cexptime%2Corigfile&top=10000